# Convert query expression to lambda in LINQPad4

Tags: linq, linqpad

While coding I had came across a LINQ query that I was able to accomplish in query syntax but not in lamda syntax. While this works fine in the application, I wanted to learn the query syntax for what I was trying to do.

Essentially, I have a database with views, CO_Leather_V and CO_LeatherSizeColor_V. I also have two classes, CuttingOrder and CuttingOrderDetail. CuttingOrderDetail contains entirely string,int and float properties. The CuttingOrder Class contains 2 string properties and a List of CuttingOrderDetails.

```
public class CuttingOrder
{
    public string cuttingOrderNo { get; set; }
    public string reserveSalesOrderNo { get; set; }
    public List<CuttingOrderDetail> details { get; set; }
}   

public class CuttingOrderDetail
{
    public string cuttingOrderNo { get; set; }
    public string reserveSalesOrderNo { get; set; }
    public string itemCode { get; set; }
    public string material { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public int qty { get; set; }
    public float squareFeet { get; set; }
    public float squareFeetUsed { get; set; }
}
```

The query expression I used to get a list of all CuttingOrders with a given SalesOrder was

```
cos = (from l in db.CO_Leather_Vs
    where l.orderNo == Globals.orderNo
    select new Globals.CuttingOrder
    {
        cuttingOrderNo = "NOT SET",
        reserveSalesOrderNo = "FAKE_SO_NO",
        details = (
            from d in db.CO_LeatherSizeColor_Vs
            select new Globals.CuttingOrderDetail
            {
                cuttingOrderNo = d.orderNo
            }
    ).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

I converted this to work in LINQPad with the following query, but I can't get anything to show on the lambda pane.

```
void Main()
{

var p = (from l in CO_Leather_V
        select new CuttingOrder
        {
        cuttingOrderNo = "NOT SET",
        reserveSalesOrderNo = "FAKE_SO_NO",
        details = (
        from d in CO_LeatherSizeColor_V
        select new CuttingOrderDetail
        {
            cuttingOrderNo = d.OrderNo
        }
        ).ToList()
        }).ToList();


p.Dump();

}


// Define other methods and classes here
public class CuttingOrder
{
    public string cuttingOrderNo { get; set; }
    public string reserveSalesOrderNo { get; set; }
    public List<CuttingOrderDetail> details { get; set; }
}   

public class CuttingOrderDetail
{
    public string cuttingOrderNo { get; set; }
    public string reserveSalesOrderNo { get; set; }
    public string itemCode { get; set; }
    public string material { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public int qty { get; set; }
    public float squareFeet { get; set; }
    public float squareFeetUsed { get; set; }
}
```

If anyone knows how to perform the linq query in lambda form or knows why LINQPad is unable to generate the lamda form it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var p = CO_Leather_V.Select(l=> new CuttingOrder
        {
            cuttingOrderNo = "NOT SET",
            reserveSalesOrderNo = "FAKE_SO_NO",
            details = CO_LeatherSizeColor_V.Select(d=>new CuttingOrderDetail  {cuttingOrderNo = d.OrderNo}).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

However, `CO_LeatherSizeColor_V` does not reference `l`, so you're going to get everything in that table, every time.  You might want something like:

```
            details = l.LeatherSizeColor.Select(d=>new CuttingOrderDetail  {cuttingOrderNo = d.OrderNo}).ToList()
```

for that line instead.